# How to Convert method from one type to another

Tags: c#, .net

Am building windows form application for a Hospital using VS2010 ON ACCESS 2010.
I want to create method that will generate a `Patient` :

```
public string GetCurrentDate()
{
    DateTime currentDate = new DateTime();
    string todaydate = currentDate.ToShortDateString().ToString();
    return todaydate;
}

public Int32 MalePatient()
{
    return 1;
}

public Int32 FemalePatient()
{
    return 2;
}

public Int32 RadomNum()
{
  Random randomNumer = new Random();
  Int32 number = randomNumer.Next(0, 1000);
  return number;
}

public string GeneratePatientNumber();
{
    patientNumber = Convert.ToString(GetCurrentDate())"+ "-"  ????
}
```

Number in this format:

```
"Date of Enrollment" + "PatientGender" +"randomNumber"
Example of Male patientNumber of type string:2012-1-10
Example of Female patientNumber of type string:2012-2-8
Female=2
Male=1
```

But I have a problem with the `GeneratePatientNumber` method which is supposed to convert the other method to a string and concatenate them as in the two samples above.

Comment: Your patientNumer examples do not match the definition. Shouldn't a patient number look like "2012-1-10 1 2234"?

Comment: it like:YYYY-GENDER-RANDOMNUM;

Comment: You write "Example of Male patientNumber of type string:" and show a date instead of a complete patient number. Please edit the example.

Comment: Example i mean:For MalePatient:2012-01-12-005 for one enrolled today but my code is fine now after the wonderful help thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be 2012-01-12-1-005? (The gender is missing.)

Comment: @ecomma to accept an answer as correct click on its tick to mark it as the accepted answer. You can show appreciation for other answers by clicking on the "up" triangle next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2
}

class PatientNumberGenerator
{
    private static Random _random = new Random();

    public string GetCurrentDate()
    {
        return DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    }

    public int RadomNum()
    {
        return _random.Next(0, 1000);
    }

    public string GeneratePatientNumber(Gender gender)
    {
        return GetCurrentDate() + "-" + (int)gender + "-" + RadomNum();
    }
}
```

You would call it with

```
var generator = new PatientNumberGenerator();
string patientNumber = generator.GeneratePatientNumber(Gender.Female);
```

Be careful with the Random class. Each time you create a new instance, it will generate a seed value from the current date and time. This determines the first random number that is generated. If you call your `RanomNum()` very fast several times then it might generate the same random number, because the internal clock in your PC has a limited resolution. This is why I declared it as a static member. This will only create `_random` one single time.

Comment: @Oliver Jacot-Descombes.This is great

Comment: how can i limit the randomNo from 9 digit to 4.

Comment: eg from 4-16-2012-11-1238822431 to 4-16-2012-11-1238

Comment: `Random` has three overloads of the `Next` method. `Next()` returns a number in the range [0 .. 2,147,483,647]; `Next(max)` => [0 .. max-1]; `Next(min, max)` => [min .. max-1]. `_random.Next(10000)` returns numbers from 0 to 9999.

Comment: Finally `_random.Next(10000).ToString("0000")` yields strings between `"0000"` and `"9999"` that always have a length of 4 and are padded with `'0'`s if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`String.Join` may be what you're looking for:

```
public string GeneratePatientNumber()
{
    return string.Join(
        "-", 
        Convert.ToString(GetCurrentDate()), 
        GetGenderCode().ToString(),
        RadomNum().ToString());
}
```

You will, of course, need to define the `GetGenderCode` method so it returns the expected code based on the patient's gender.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this:

```
public string GetCurrentDate()
{
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
string todaydate = currentDate.ToShortDateString().ToString();
return todaydate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little refactoring:

```
public enum PatientGender
{
    Male = 1,
    Female
}

public int RandomNum()
{
    return new Random().Next(0, 1000);
}

var patientNumber = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}",
                                  DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                  (int)PatientGender.Male,
                                  RandomNum());
```

Gives the following output:

```
2012-01-11-1-586
```